# Downgrade MySQL 8.0.20 to 8.0.19 on Ubuntu for using XtraBackup

Tags: mysql, backup, ubuntu, mysql-8.0, percona-tools

With MySQL 8.0.20 currently installed on Ubuntu, I am unable to use Percona XtraBackup 2.3.7 due to [breaking changes introduced in MySQL 8.0.20](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/04/28/percona-xtrabackup-8-x-and-mysql-8-0-20/#:%7E:text=On%20Monday%2C%20April%2027%2C%202020,x%20series.).

How can we downgrade MySQL 8.0.20 to 8.0.19 on Ubuntu, which I believe is the latest MySQL version currently supported by XtraBackup? `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config` does not allow us to select a minor version.

Must the current data be backup using mysqldump before the downgrade, and restored using the dump after the downgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtrabackup 8.0.12 should work with MySQL 8.0.20

[Percona xtrabackup 8.0.12 release](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/06/08/percona-xtrabackup-for-all-versions-of-mysql-percona-server-for-mongodb-updates-dbaas-cli-tool-0-2-0-release-roundup-june-8-2020/)

> Percona XtraBackup 8.0.12 now supports backup and restore processing for all versions of MySQL up to and including 8.0.20; previous versions of Percona XtraBackup will not work with MySQL 8.0.20 and higher.